# What is the meaning of "recurring wish" in this paragraph?

Tags: meaning

I find this paragraph is very confusing to understand, it is from IMDB synopsis  of Good Will Hunting (1997) movie.

> Sean points out that Will is so adept at anticipating future failure
>   in his personal and romantic relationships, that he either allows them
>   to fizzle out or deliberately bails in order to avoid the risk of
>   future emotional pain. When Will then provides a whimsical reply to
>   Sean's very serious query of what he wants to do with his life, Sean
>   simply shows him the door. When Will further tells his best friend
>   Chuckie (Ben Affleck) that he wants to be a laborer for the rest of
>   his life, Chuckie becomes brutally honest with Will: He believes it's
>   an "insult" for Will to waste his potential as a laborer, and that his
>   **recurring wish** is to knock on Will's door in the morning when he picks
>   him up for work and find that he just isn't there, that he has left
>   without saying goodbye. Chuckie's honesty hits home with Will more
>   than anyone else's, even Sean, a trained professional.

So Please explain this paragraph.

Comment: You're gonna have to identify one or two phrases that you don't understand. This site is for specific questions about specific things you need help with–not explaining whole paragraphs.

Comment: @AlanCarmack I didn't understand from "recurring wish" from the paragraph. it would be great if you explain whole paragraph. thank you.

Comment: @Stephen Bendl Thank you for posting the meaning, can you post the meaning of last sentence of this paragraph, I didn't understand the words "honesty hits home" means what? Is it pun?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well there's a lot there, in terms of the whole paragraph. I'm not sure anyone can really explain the whole thing to you. In reference to "recurring wish," which you mentioned, the meaning is that Chuckie wishes every day that Will won't be there when he (Chuckie) knocks on Will's door.

Recurring: occurring or appearing at intervals
[(Mirriam Webster)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/recurring)

Therefore "Recurring wish" means that the wish happens again and again.